# British school terminology "given yards"

Tags: meaning, british-english

In a recent Tom Scott video, an older gentleman who is currently serving as the town crier of Honiton [recounts his childhood involvement](https://youtu.be/nbafT2w0cCQ?t=271) in the "hot penny festival".

> We used to wear gloves, hobnail boots, old clothes... and then when we got back in school, we'd be given 100 yards for skiving off.

I know "skiving off" is slang for skipping/ditching/cutting, i.e. failing to go to school when required; but what does "given 100 yards" mean?  It's clearly some sort of punishment, but the only options I can think of are a 100-yard dash (which is barely a punishment at all) or being told to write sentences for 100 yards of paper (which seems incredibly harsh because that's hundreds of pages of text).

Comment: Yard is the short for yardstick, so they probably refer to the use of a “stick” as punishments.

Comment: That sounds like wild speculation. Do you have any examples of modern use of "yard" in that sense?

Comment: Yard 3.  short for yardstick (sense 2). Yardstick 2. a graduated stick, one yard long, used for measurement. Collins Dictionary

Comment: I'm aware yard can be used as a shorthand for yardstick -- but you have provided no evidence that this is british slang for being beaten as a punishment. That's the speculation I'm referring to, not what you call a yardstick.

Comment: I suggest this as a comment, not as an answer. But yardsticks were present in schools, and I may reasonably assume they were possibly used as sticks for whatever use.

Comment: Teachers use stick for discipline at Chase Street, but not for whacking. 
*The Chase Street stick is a yardstick like the ones teachers once might have used to whack the back of a student's hand or backside.* https://eu.onlineathens.com/story/news/education/2014/08/09/teachers-use-stick-discipline-chase-street-not-whacking/15522758007/

Comment: Taking into account the lack of useful context, is it not at least fairly clear that being 'given 100 yards…' there means being told to run 100 yards, as fast the victim could?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Why would "run 100 yards" be more clearly what he meant rather than any of the other proposed options? The only offered answer has been "100 lashes with a cane".

Comment: Of course 'yard' could have been short for 'yard stick' in which case exponents of that theory will be able to give examples.

If the suggestion is that '100 yards' meant '100 thwacks with a yard stick' who doubts that either the stick or the boy would fall to pieces long before the count was thwacked through?

In complete contrast, last time I looked running laps or lengths had been part of the games teachers' punishment list ever since there were tales of school life.

FYI even without quote marks, "100 lashes with a cane" is your personal transliteration, not an 'offered answer.'

Comment: By the way M*A*S*H just now gave me the only example I've ever noticed, when Charles told Hawkeye: 'That'll be 15 yards for acting like an idiot.' (M*A*S*H Series 7, Episode 11: 'Points of View' about 43 minutes in. I hope you take my word for the irrelevance of the context.)

The script provides no useful clue but that even swimming, let alone running 15 yards could hardly be a real punishment;  not physically, though trotting down to pool or track and changing twice could be a real nuisance.

Hawkeye's reaction suggests it doesn't mean any kind of thrashing , either.

Comment: Does that not suggests '15 yards' might be not the distance run but rather, a starter's handicap?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not relevant. "Fifteen yards for X" is a reference to american football, where the standard penalty for misbehavior is moving the ball back by 10, 15, or 20 yards.  As in "fifteen yards for holding" or "pass interference, 10 yards and repeat the down".  Charles is not applying an actual punishment, but humorously taking the role of a referee to declare Hawkeye's actions an offense that can be penalized.

Comment: Sorry Darth Not only is that highly relevant; fairly clearly, it's the whole point.

Where do you think American or Australian Football or their like came from, but English public schools in general; Rugby in particular?

Today yes, '15 yards for X' most often refers to American Football but the point is that it clearly refers to all games like that, in which misbehaviour might see the ball moved back X yards for whatever infringement.

Would you really like to argue whether my 'starter's handicap' included all 're-starter's…' or 'referee's handicapps'?

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser, in Sue Thomas F.B. Eye , Series 1 Episode 12, The Heist this morning, a character said that her boyfriend had played football at college and '… (mublumble) the most yards on campus…' That proves nothing but doesn't it suggest football players are proud to collect the yards they either achieve for themselves, or are given?

Answer (score -3):

Yard is an old synonym for rod. Rod in the context of the video probably means beating, although he is likely exaggerating when he said he got 100 beatings for skipping school.

Comment: I've never heard '100 yards' used in this sense. He would be more likely to say "We got the cane".

Comment: "Yard is an old synonym for rod." This is true, but if the OED is to be trusted as to when this use fell out of style, this man would have to be older than Shakespeare. Please [edit] to add examples/references from present-day English.

Comment: @Laurel This is almost certainly the right answer, so I suspect it's an anachronism.